# How would you use list comprehension to output True with an If statement?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a debugger to get rid of bad files like this:

```
from os import path

for i in attachments: #Find bad attachments
    if not path.isfile(i):
        sys.exit("The attachment provided does not exist.")  #Raise exception
```

What is the best way to do this? Is this the most efficient way?

I tried doing this: `[sys.exit(...) if not pathisfile(i) for i in attachments]` but it just showed syntax error.

Comment: Why would you use a list comprehension?  You're not constructing a list.  That's what they're for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the most efficient way is to do a python [assertion](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_assert.asp):

```
from os import path

for i in attachments:
  assert path.isfile(i),"the attachment you provided does not exist."
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is to be put after the iterator (for loop), not before which caused you an error, here's your corrected code.

```
[sys.exit("The attachment provided does not exist.") for i in attachments if not path.isfile(i)]
```

But I think using a list comprehension is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `any()` function, which you can call with a list comprehension or (more simply) a generator expression:

```
if any(not path.isfile(i) for i in attachments):
    sys.exit("The attachment provided does not exist.")
```

or equivalently, with `all()`:

```
if not all(path.isfile(i) for i in attachments):
    sys.exit("The attachment provided does not exist.")
```